# Type of operand of binary AND operator

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

What type of operators use the logical AND operator (&)?
I need to put in AND a short `a` and a "number" `m` varying from 1 to 16 and obtain another short `b`.
Of that primitive type must be `m`?

Example:

```
? m = ...; //with 1 <= m <= 16
short a = 2;
short b = a & m;
```

The examples I have seen are like:

```
short b = a & 0xY;
```

How can I translate `m` value to `Y` in such a way that the operation AND is correct?
So `b` contains the last `m` bits of `a`.

If I use m as int, I don't obtain the correct result.

I read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) page about Operators but it does not say anything about that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last `m` bits out of `a`, you need a bit mask with the least significant `m` bits set to `1` and the rest set to `0`.

You can get this by subtracting one from a power of 2 equal to 2<sup>m</sup>, or `1` shifted left `m` times.

```
int bitmask = (1 << m) - 1;
```

E.g. if `m` is `4`, then `1 << 4` is `16`, minus one is `15`, or `0b1111`, 4 `1`s.

Then you can use the bitwise-and operator `&` to get a value of `b`.  But beware, this operator (among others) performs *binary numeric promotion*.  Binary numeric promotion ensures that with differing types that the narrower type is widened to be the same type as the wider type.  But it also widens both to `int` if they aren't already `int`.

This means that both sides are promoted at least to `int` before the operation occurs.  Cast it back to `short`.

```
short b = (short) (a & bitmask);
```

Note that because of binary numeric promotion, the type of the bitmask might as well be `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to 'translate `m` to `Y` at all. You just have to evaluate `a & m`.

If you have a problem when doing that, you have failed to state what it is. You have certainly forgotten to cast the result back to `short`.